# Debug log is filled with USER_INFO

Tags: debug, userinfo

My debug log is completely filled with USER_INFO. I adjusted the log levels in all possible combinations hoping to get rid of this. But that didn't help. Can some one please help me understand what could have caused this?

[image: Sample Debug Log]

> **Update**: This has been **listed on Known Issues** : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000182fJQAQ. Please click on 'This issue affects me' button to let them know how many developers are facing this issue.

Comment: is this a VF controller?

Comment: Also getting the same error for about a week now. Have tried also sorts of combinations on the log levels including the one from Santanu but no joy.

Comment: Yes that's a controller class.

Comment: yes, I've seen this too but only in VF controllers; log levels make no difference

Comment: Is this related to Summer  '16 preview?

Comment: Just wanted to add that you're definitely not alone, I'm having the same problem.  Debug logs are all but useles these days and there's more and more posts on here and on the developer forums about this.  No word from Salesforce as yet

Comment: @ministe2003 Salesforce hasn't listed this as a known issue yet. I think it is not aware of the issue.

Comment: It's happening to me too. Maddening and very hard to debug now!

Comment: Please all indicate 'This affects me' on the known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000182fJQAQ Probably the only way to get it resolved quicker.

Comment: @Guy I updated my question with this. Lets see if we can reach at least 100 votes to get Salesforce's  attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I had the same error, and after much digging, may have a solution.

In the debug log area, delete all logging levels and all traces.

Then in the dev console, do this query (using the tooling API):

```
SELECT Id FROM TraceFlag
```

Delete all the resulting rows. There was one row that kept regenerating (probably because I was in the dev console and it corresponded to that).

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That fixed the issue...Thank you for posting your findings :)

Comment: Curious that the [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000182fJQAQ) shows this as Fixed yet none of the orgs are marked as fixed - and there's a statement saying it is scheduled for Winter 17. Your workaround did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, it only works sometimes... sorry.

Comment: if you create your own Debug Levels, it will not keep generating any row. 1#Create your own debug log level. 2# Delete the default Debug log level generated by Salesforce. 3# Assign your user to new Debug log level

Comment: @cropredy This is not fixed on any of my orgs....Probably they have mistakenly marked it as fixed. Even Caspar's solution is not working now...it used to work.

Comment: They said it is fixed and at the end they put this note "We expect to fix this issue in Winter ’17. Safe harbor applies." Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out this log levels:

[image]

Otherwise, try to select level on higher side.

Comment: This did not help. I still get the same USER_INFO. I selected everything to be FINEST and also NONE....Both the cases didn't help. When I set everything to FINEST I reach maximum debug log size...but this USER_INFO doesn't go away.